# HDInsight Hive not finding SerDe jar in ADD JAR statement

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I've uploaded json-serde-1.1.9.2.jar to the blob store with path "/lib/" and added

```
ADD JAR /lib/json-serde-1.1.9.2.jar
```

But am getting

```
/lib/json-serde-1.1.9.2.jar does not exist
```

I've tried it without the path and also provided the full url to the `ADD JAR` statement with the same result.

Would really appreciate some help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include the scheme, then Hive is going to look on the local filesystem (you can see the code around line 768 of [the source](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState.java))

when you included the URI, make sure you use the full form:

```
ADD JAR wasb:///lib/json-serde-1.1.9.2.jar
```

If that still doesn't work, provide your updated command as well as some details about how you are launching the code.  Are you RDP'd in to the cluster running via the Hive shell, or running remote via PowerShell or some other API?

Comment: I had tried all sorts of path formats, didn't know that was possible.  Thanks once again @RickH

Comment: Rationalizing blob storage Uri's to Hadoop Scheme Uri's seems to be a common point of confusion.  Glad to help.