# "Can not validate" error using JSON SerDe with Hive in HDInsight

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to implement JSON SerDe in HDInsight to work with files in JSON format. I read [HDInsight Hive not finding SerDe jar in ADD JAR statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426445/hdinsight-hive-not-finding-serde-jar-in-add-jar-statement) but when trying to run a query to create a table, the cluster returns the error message:

```
return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask Can not validate serde.org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
```

What does this error message mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that the serde class is not found anywhere in the current class path.

The repo for the SerDe at https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde has some info for how to build/download the necessary jar file.  After obtaining the jar, you will have to either load it into the cluster at provisioning time using *HiveConfiguration.AdditionalLibraries* ([example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/04/15/customizing-hdinsight-cluster-provisioning-via-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx)) or load it at runtime from WASB using the syntax shown in the [question you linked to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/04/15/customizing-hdinsight-cluster-provisioning-via-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx).